# Не работает z-index

Tags: html, css

Есть два элемента

```
<div class="menu_1">
            321321
            </div>
            <div class="menu_2">
            11
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu_1{
background-color:#333333;
height:300px;

z-index: 1; 

}

.menu_2{
background-color:#cccccc;
height:400px;

z-index: 0; 

}
```

Но почему то первый блок не перекрывает второй, а идут поочередно, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он и не должен перекрывать, если не задан стиль position. Задайте например position : absolute

И z-index ставьте больше 1, т.к.   это дефолтное положение.

Comment: 1 - это не дефаултное значение. И даже 0 - не дефаултное. 0 - это уровень фона. А дефаултное значение `auto` и оно не создаёт контекст, в отличие от _любого_ числа.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index`, отличный от `auto` только создаёт новый контекст и управляет расположением элемента поверх или под другими элементами внутри родительского контекста. За пределы родительского контекста выбраться нельзя, как-то взаимодействовать с элементами вне него - тоже.

Помимо `z-index` контекст создают `opacity`, `transform` и `position` при своих недефаултных значениях. Возможно, ещё что-то - навскидку в голову не приходит.

Контекс никак не связан с расположением элемента по x и y, поэтому наложения одного элемента на другой не происходит и не должно происходить. Для наложения надо использовать позиционирование, либо отрицательный margin.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию у ваших блоков стоит position:static, соответственно, они выводятся в общем потоке элементов страницы - один за другим - последовательно. Свойство z-index работает только с установленным позиционирование, т.е. position: {relative, absolute, fixed} Задайте второму блоку отрицательный margin, например, margin-top: -50px и позиционирование блокам. Увидите ожидаемое наложение.
Обязательно усвойте значения, которые может принимать свойство position и как они работают. Понимание этих основ избавит от многих проблем в будущем.

.menu_1{
background-color:#333333;
height:300px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2; 
}

.menu_2{
background-color:#cccccc;
height:400px;
margin-top: -50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1; 
}